# Can you add and remove section tags? Foundation HTML

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I am trying to create a dynamic "section tabs" based on a user logging in. As a 'guest' they get the first two sections. If the login as 'user 1' the get sections 1,2,3,5 and 'user 2' gets 1,2,4,5. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="large-9 push-3 columns">
<div class="section-container tabs" data-section="tabs">
    <section class="section">
        <p class="title"><a href="#">Section 1</a></p>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Content of section 1.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section">
        <p class="title"><a href="#">Section 2</a></p>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Content of section 2.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="chicagoSection" class="section" style="display: none">
        <p class="title"><a href="#">Chicago</a></p>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Content of section 3.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="detroitSection" class="section" style="display: none">
        <p class="title"><a href="#">Detroit</a></p>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Content of section 4.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="userInfo" class="section" style="display: none">
        <p class="title"><a href="#">RSVP</a></p>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Content of section 5.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</div>
```

And my javascipt:

```
if (userOne) 
    {
        document.getElementById("chicagoSection").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("userInfo").style.display="block";
    }
if (userTwo) 
    {
        document.getElementById("detroitSection").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("userInfo").style.display="block";
    }
```

When the code is executed, the section tabs are placed on top of each other. Is there a dynamic way to do what I want or do I have to fix positions? Another option was to wrap the whole section in a div and hide it, or show it based on the user, but duplicating that HTML is too hokie for me.

I am using Foundation 4 css with their inherent javascript. For added information, without setting the 'display-none' the sections are just fine.

Thanks in advance!

SOLUTION:

```
    var section = document.createElement('section');
    var title = "Section " + count;
    var content = "Content of new section."

    section.className = "section";
    section.innerHTML ='<p class="title" style="left: ' + (count - 1) * 86 + 'px;"><a href="#">' + title + '</a></p><div class="content"><p>' + content + '</p></div>';
    count += 1;
    document.getElementById('sectionContainer').appendChild(section);
```

I found this resource http://pastebin.com/QBMEJ2pq and adapted it to my purpose. The 86 constant was defined in my css. I know there is more than likely a 'proper' way to do this (IE creating all the elements and nesting them) but unfortunately I couldn't find the resources. If anyone could post how to create the innerHTML better I would appreciate it.

Comment: I am not sure if downvoting this question would be appropriate... What you are doing is **terribly wrong** - you just **cannot** implement security on the client side!

Comment: (forgetting that this has something to do with "security"): Can it be that you are using absolute positioning? Please post your CSS (if any).

Comment: I do intend to implement security, but for the purpose of this question I made it simple.

Comment: @BobMoore Could you post an answer with your solution and accept it instead of updated your question to put the answer inside it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
var section = document.createElement('section');
var title = "Section " + count;
var content = "Content of new section."

section.className = "section";
section.innerHTML ='<p class="title" style="left: ' + (count - 1) * 86 + 'px;"><a href="#">' + title + '</a></p><div class="content"><p>' + content + '</p></div>';
count += 1;
document.getElementById('sectionContainer').appendChild(section);
```

I found this resource http://pastebin.com/QBMEJ2pq and adapted it to my purpose.